# new environment with one optional and second must have arguments

Tags: macros

Probably this question has been asked before, but I could not find a satisfactory answer anywhere. Is there a way to define a \newenviroment with an optional and a must have argument. e.g something like

```
\newenvironment[2]{
do something if #1 is there else leave alone
do something with #2
}{}
```

My apologies in advance if question sounds too vague.

Comment: Load the `etoolbox` package and write `\newenvironment{envname}[2][]{\ifbool{isempty{#1}}{do something}{}do something with #2}{}` in your preamble. That should work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `xparse` package. It provides variuos options for declaring new environments:

```
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment
\NewDocumentEnvironment
\RenewDocumentEnvironment
\ProvideDocumentEnvironment
```

These have the syntax

```
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment {<environment>} {<arg spec>}
{<start code>} {<end code>}
```

Futher, to check whether the first argument is present, you can use one of these:

```
\IfNoValueTF
\IfValueTF
\IfValueTF
...
```

`\IfNoValueTF` has, for example the syntax of

```
\IfNoValueTF {#1}
{ \DoSomethingJustWithMandatoryArgument {#2} }
{ \DoSomethingWithBothArguments {#1} {#2} }
```

For more details, please refer to `xparse` package documentation.

One simple example, (in the absence of any specific MWE/need)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenviron}{om}{%
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
    {#2}
    {#1#2}%
    }{%
    }
\begin{document}
  \begin{myenviron}
    No optional argument
  \end{myenviron}
  \begin{myenviron}[\tiny]
    With optional argument
  \end{myenviron}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is just a model example and you have to modify/write your own as per your needs.

Comment: Hey Harish, in your example you defined myenviron as taking 2 arguments .. but you passed just the one optional argument. Actually that is more refined part of my problem. What would be the syntax to use with such an environment?

Comment: Technically the `N` in the first call to `myenviron` and `W` in the second call act as the mandatory argument in Harish's example.

Comment: I can understand that N/H being taken as the second args in the two case. But is there a way to have something on the lines of say \begin{myenviron}[]{} or \begin{myenviron}{}

Comment: @user3750702 I am sure that I understand. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @HarishKumar Taking the example of newcommand if I define \newcommand\mycommand[2][] then I can either call \mycommand as \mycommand[a]{b} {do stuff } or \mycommand{} {do stuff}. In the second case \mycommand understand that first optional arg is not passed. Is there a similar syntax in \newenvironment ?

Comment: @user3750702 Hmm. That is what I did in my code. First one doesn't have [<optiona arg>]` and second one has `[\tiny]`.